# `UITableViewCell` call function from parent TableView

Tags: swift, uitableview, delegates

I have a UI widget as follows

```
class ProfileBubbleCell: UITableViewCell {

    var roundImageView: UIImageView?

    override func awakeFromNib() {

        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.contentView.backgroundColor = Color.red
        initImage()
    }

    private func initImage(){

        let imageView = UIImageView()

        let width = self.frame.width
        let height = self.frame.height

        let img_width  = height - 4
        let img_height = img_width

        let y = 2
        let x = width/2 - img_width/2

        imageView.frame = CGRect(
              x: x, y: CGFloat(y), width: img_width, height: img_height
        )

        let rounded = imageView
            .makeRounded()
            .border(width:2.0, color:Color.white.cgColor)

        // attach and save reference
        self.addSubview(rounded)
        self.roundImageView = rounded
    }

    private func loadImage(){
    // @TODO: call parent function

    }
}
```

And in `loadImage`, I would like to call the parent's image loading view, and when the image is loaded, display it in `roundImageView`. `ProfileBubbleCell` is really meant to be as generic as possible, its only concern is making the image round and centering it.

This looks like a very common use case and I would like to `delegate` the loading image task to the parent, but I am not sure how to express it.

In the parent I instantiate the cell as follows:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ProfileBubbleCell", for: indexPath) as! ProfileBubbleCell
```

Comment: Well, there's your answer. When you say `let cell  = tableView.dequeueReusableCell`, set the cell's `delegate` to `self`. I'm presuming here you know how to make a protocol-and-delegate architecture so that some method of the parent becomes a delegate method so the cell can call it on its `delegate`.

Comment: @matt could you provide an example of protocol-and-delegate ?

Comment: No, that's well documented here and elsewhere. Nor is that the only solution. Another is just to walk the responder hierarchy from the cell to the parent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here show you some about delegate use.

```
// 1) define delegate.
protocol ProfileBubbleCellDelegate { 
  func getImage() -> UIImage?
}


class ProfileBubbleCell: UITableViewCell { 

  // 2) declare a variable of ProfileBubbleCellDelegate
  weak var delegate: ProfileBubbleCellDelegate?

  //  
  func configure() {
    self.roundImageView.image = delegate.getImage()
  }
}

// when dequeueReuseCell on cellForRow(at:)
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {  
  guard let cell  = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ProfileBubbleCell", for: indexPath) as ProfileBubbleCell else { return UITableView() }
  // 3) assign delegate to tableView's superView, maybe it's a UIViewController or UIView on your class.
  cell.delegate = self
  cell.configure()
  return cell
}

// 4) extension Your class who be assigned delegate of ProfileBubbleCellDelegate
//    and implement delegate's method.
extension YourClass: ProfileBubbleCellDelegate { 
  func getImage() -> UIImage? { 
    // 5) provide image.
    return hereProvideYourImage
  }
}

// or if you want immediately download image when cell.roundedImageView need it.
// modify the getImage() of Delegate like this.
protocol ProfileBubbleCellDelegate { 

  func getImage(completion: @escaping ((UIImage?) -> Void))
}

// then the extension implement will be 
extension YourClass: ProfileBubbleCellDelegate { 
  func getImage(completion: @escaping ((UIImage?) -> Void)) { 
    downloadImageTask.downloadImage(url: imageUrl, completion: { downloadedImage in  
      // because completion will be passed on other closure of downloadImage(completion:), 
      //   so delegate method need add `@escaping` that means the completion can escape from itself closure.
      completion?(downloadedImage)
     })
  }
}

// don't forget replace called method on cell. 
class ProfileBubbleCell: UITableViewCell { 
  // ...   
  func configure() { 
    delegate.getImage(completion: { downloadedImage in 
      DispatchQueue.main.async { 
        self.roundImageView.image = downloadedImage
      }
    })
  }
}
```